# Meaning of ったらねえ

Tags: grammar

> これだから女ってやつは移ろいやすい**ったらねえ**。

"That's why girls are so variable". I guess.

What about **ったらねえ**? I found that **ったら** you can use when you tired of repeating yourself or when you are exasperated with somebody for not listening to you. So what would **ったらねえ** mean?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6772/1478

Comment: I was trying to understand the sentence. It's probably along the lines of: Because (から) that (これ) is (だ) \[so], girls (女ってやつ) are easy (やすい) to change (移ろい) [their mind]. Or change [their mind] easily. Let's call this A. If ったらねえ is short for といったらねえ, which is a colloquial form of といったらない, then A といったらない: If you say A, than that is not the case. Which supposedly means that A is an understatement. って is probably used to [categorize](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/09/tte-particle.html#categorization) やつ (person, derogatory or familiar?) with 女...

Comment: ...The only thing I can't explain/understand is why 移ろう is in the conjunctive (連用形) form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

〜ねえ is a colloquial form of 〜ない, and 〜といったらない is a fixed phrase meaning "very" or "extremely".

Comment: Can we automatically call a translation "meaning"?  I never think of "very" or "extremely" when I say ったらねえ or といったらない in real life as a Japanese-speaker.  All I think of is "There is no way to express ~~."

Comment: @TokyoNagoya I cite デジタル大辞泉: （「…といったらない」の形で）程度が、これ以上に…なことはない、極めて…だ、の意を表す。

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: Thank for your comment:  I was aware of the definitions but I have always felt it to be "There is no way to express ~~." and wondered why this not included in the  explanations available.