# といったらなかった meaning

Tags: word-choice, usage

I came across the following sentence in a novel:

> フランツ司祭が体調を崩して寝たきりになってからの村の連中の態度といったらなかったよ。

As for some context, フランツ司祭 is someone who had passed away recently, and the villagers were not incredibly fond of the priest. My rough translation for this sentence would be "Even after the priest's health degraded, the villagers never showed up to help."

That second half of that translation is mostly just guessing from context. What I would like to know is what 「態度といったらなかった」means here in this context. What does "they didn't have an attitude" really mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6772/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80086/5010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression is 「といったらない」with several variations.

> ～といったらありはしない
> ～といったらありゃしない
> ～ったらありゃしない
> ～といったらない
> ～ったらない

[『精選版 日本国語大辞典』](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-2065985)により

> 状態を表わす語をうけて、それが、度がはずれていて、はなはだしいことを、驚いたり、あきれたりしていう。…ときたら大変なものだ。としたことが。とだしてはない。
> ※牛肉と馬鈴薯（1901）〈国木田独歩〉「其時の心持といったら無(ナ)いね、何だか斯(か)う馬鹿野郎！といふやうな心持がしてねェ」

[『実用日本語表現辞典』](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%82%83%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

> 主に形容詞の後ろにつき、その形容詞を強調する口語表現。「ったら」の部分は、「と言ったら」が略されたものである。例えば、「羨ましいったらありゃしない」と言った場合には、非常に羨ましいことを意味し、「みっともないったらありゃしない」と言った場合には、非常にみっともないと思っていることを意味する。

The phrase seems to have morphed out of contractions and omissions.

- 「ったら」=「と言ったら」=「と言えば」=「～ことと言えば」
- 「ない」=「ありゃしない」=「ありはしない」=「ありえない」
- 「他に」is left unsaid in these expressions.

Therefore, 「Xといったらない」means

> Xのことと言えば、X以外のことはありえない

namely,

> X is the ultimate example of its kind.
> X is in a class of its own.
> There is nothing like X!

> フランツ司祭が体調を崩して寝たきりになってからの村の連中の態度といったらなっかったよ。

means

> When フランツ司祭 got terribly sick and became bedridden, the attitude of the guys in the village couldn't have been worse.

Or if you want to spice it up with a little sarcasm:

> When フランツ司祭 got terribly sick and became bedridden, the villagers' attitude was priceless.

Comment: Thank you, I had a hard time identifying this.

Answer (score -1):

態度 / と / いったら / なかった/。

```
態度 == attitude
と == (i don't know how to explain)
いたっら == is
なかった　== bad (in only this sentence)
```

normally ”なかった”　meaning is "nothing" and this is past participle.
"ない" is now participle.